# Changes axis projection from 2D to 3D in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, plot, 3d

Is it possible to change the projection of an axis once created in matplotlib please?

I'm trying to write generalised code for plotting, making each plot a function which takes the axis to work on as an argument.

eg.

```
def plot_this(ax):
    ax.plot((1,2,3))

def plot_that(ax):
    ax.plot_surface(etc.)
```

However, for 3d plotting (e.g. using plot_surface) a 3d projection is needed (e.g. initialised by ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')) which differs from the standard 2d axis.

If my function is given an ax with a 2D projection, how can I change this to 3D?

Thanks